# Copying an entity in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to copy an entity (in this case a PageEntity) in JPA.

This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public PageEntity copyPage(Long pageId, PageEntity pageEntity) {


        PageEntity pageToCopy=new PageEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(findOne(pageId),pageToCopy);

        //Save new template
        TemplateEntity templateCopy = pageToCopy.getTemplate();
        templateCopy.setBlocks(null);
        templateCopy.setId(null);

        TemplateEntity copiedTemplate = templateDao.saveAndFlush(templateCopy);

        //Save new page
        pageEntity.setTemplate(copiedTemplate);

        Long copiedPageId=pageDao.saveAndFlush(pageEntity).getId();

        //Save blocks and parameters
        List<BlockEntity> blockCopy = pageToCopy.getTemplate().getBlocks();

        for(BlockEntity block : blockCopy){
            block.setId(null);
            block.setTemplateId(copiedTemplate.getId());
           for(ParameterEntity parameter : block.getParameters()){
               parameter.setId(null);
           }
           blockDao.saveAndFlush(block);
        }

        return pageDao.findOne(copiedPageId);

    }
```

The problem is, that I can not alter the id - I always get an exception:

```
"identifier of an instance of de.smava.dao.entity.TemplateEntity was altered from 1 to null; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of de.smava.dao.entity.TemplateEntity was altered from 1 to null",
```

I totally get what this means - but still. I need to copy a whole page and create a new Id. How to achieve this?

Comment: If your model allows it clearing the identifiers should work - _if the entities are detached_, i.e. they must not be cached in the Hibernate session anymore. Alternatively you might want to consider creating a clone of the entities, e.g. by making use of a mapping library such as mapstruct or Dozer.

Comment: Thanks for your hint :) Will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply detach the entity before the copy:

```
 yourEntityManager.detach(copiedTemplate);
 //Save new page
 pageEntity.setTemplate(copiedTemplate);
```