# JPA and Hibernate - Select same object twice and get two instances

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am using spring boot version 3.1.6 with appropiate jpa and hibernate dependencies.

And now I try the following:

- Select a (tree-like) Object that can get pretty large
- Execute a complex data migration on that object with a lot of parameters. The outcome is more or less "impossible" to predict before the migration.
- Generate a list of changes that have been caused by the migration.

The easiest way would be:

1. Select the object twice
2. Migrate one of them
3. Compare the migrated one with the unchanged one

However, when just selecting the object twice using `repository.findById(...)`, I do get two variables that point to the exact same object because the internal entity manager just returns the result of the first query when using the second find.
But since both variables are the same object, migrating one will also migrate the second one and therefore there will not be any changes.

My question: Is there a way to force `repository.findById` to return a second object - like a copy?

Comment: instead of selecting the object twice from DB, you can copy the object to a new object or maybe u can use entityManager.detach to detach the entity as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651718/copying-an-entity-in-jpa?rq=3